# Adding AjaxControls 4.5 using Visual Studio 2012 under toolbox is not working

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Installed the latest version of Ajax Controls from  http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com
when  adding the Ajax Controls under toolbox, I am getting the following messages:
 there are no components in AjaxControlToolkit.dll that can be placed on the toolbox?

I also install it through Manage Nugget packages online.

I have Visual Studio 2012 Professional Version

Any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a empty web Application and followed the same Installation above and  I was able to Add Ajax controls under Toolbox.

Must be  some conflict between the components added to the default web Application and empty Web application  created by Visual Studio 2012.

MsAjaxBundle  reference is a part of default web application that does not exist when creating new web Application

More comments are appreciated!